# How do I create a polygon layer of high slope (>58%) area from a DEM in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am hoping to get from a slope raster (calculated from a 10m resolution DEM) to a polygon of areas above a certain grade (58%). I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1. I have used the Raster Calculator tool to remove decimal places in my raster values and then run the INT tool to convert it to Integer. Now I need to remove values below 58% before using the Raster to Polygon tool. I am unclear on how to do this. Should I use the Raster Calculator tool?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model. Questions should be several paragraphs long, with details on the software, data, and task, as well as what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. A single sentence Question is unlikely to survive automatic closure review. Please help us to help you by making an [Edit] to the Question.

Comment: Thanks Vince, Hopefully this edited version is more illustrative of my situation.

Comment: Isn't this just a classification, followed by raster-to-polygon on the resultant Boolean mask?

Comment: yes most likely, I am just trying to figure out how to navigate the raster classification/reclassification tools.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm and here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4zwIUbxq_I

Comment: Often in these cases the resulting polygons will contain many isolated single polygons within the larger or "strings" of pixels touching corner to corner, and you may want to get rid of these.  There are some approaches that can be applied to vector polygons like using the Eliminate tool, and in rasterizing using simplify, but there are other approaches that work on rasters (e.g. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/generalizing-classified-output-by-removing-small-isolated-regions.htm), and then the conversion is made to a vector polygon.

Comment: A heatmap could be used to generate a gradient, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do reclassify.
Put a value for those >58 and those <58%.

Next is Raster to Polygon.